# how to avoid the extra copy when calling async function taking a lambda callback

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013, copy

I have an async function `foo_async` that takes a callback (lambda) and executes it on a new thread after capturing it by value.

```
void foo_async(const std::function<void()>& callback)
{
    std::thread t([callback]() // capture callback by value
    {
        callback();
    });

    t.detach();
}
```

I use this in function `bar` that itself takes callback

```
void bar(const std::function<void()>& callback)
{    
    auto barCallback = [callback] // capture original callback by value
    { 
        callback();
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl; 
    };

    foo_async(barCallback);
}
```

Then finally, I invoke `bar` from `main`

```
int main()
{
    std::string s("hello ");
    bar([s]{ std::cout << s; }); // capture some state
    std::cin.get();
}
```

The problem I have is the string `s` in `main` is copied *thrice*, once in `main`, once in `bar` and once in `foo_async`. But ideally, it should have only been necessary to copy it twice - in `main` to put it into the lambda, and in `foo_async` to execute on another thread. The copy in `bar` should have been avoided since it executes synchronously.

Is there any way I could avoid the extra copy of `s`? Note that I cannot capture the original callback by reference in bar, because foo_async needs to execute it on a new thread.

Comment: Threads has access to other threads memory, so why do you think that you cannot do it by reference?

Comment: The original memory would be freed after the synchronous part has completed. So the new thread needs its own copy of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things: 1) don't keep a local copies of lambdas around, and 2) *move* the function objects into the lambdas:

```
void foo_async(std::function<void()> callback)
{
    std::thread([c = std::move(callback)]() { c(); }).detach();
}

void bar(std::function<void()> callback)
{    
    foo_async([c = std::move(callback)]() { c(); std::cout << "world\n"; });
}

int main()
{
    std::string s("hello ");
    bar([s = std::move(s)]{ std::cout << s; });
}
```